# Bootstrapped Latin Partition

Tags: cross-validation, sampling, bootstrap, validation, train-test-split

I'm having trouble understanding the Bootstrapped Latin partition method (as presented in [Statistical validation of classification and calibration models using bootstrapped Latin partitions](https://www.academia.edu/33709163/Statistical_validation_of_classification_and_calibration_models_using_bootstrapped_Latin_partitions) and illustrated in [On Splitting Training and Validation Set](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328589123_On_Splitting_Training_and_Validation_Set_A_Comparative_Study_of_Cross-Validation_Bootstrap_and_Systematic_Sampling_for_Estimating_the_Generalization_Performance_of_Supervised_Learning)). In the latter paper, Fig. 2 shows the image pasted below [image]

and the following description:

> In BLP, the number of partitions (i.e., splits) k is to be
> speciﬁed by the user. For m partitions, m mutually exclusive
> data splitting indices are generated and ~1/m of the samples
> are used for validation, and the remaining samples are used
> for training. Then the row indices for a class are selected,
> randomized and concatenated to form a long vector **k** containing the indices of all classes. This vector is then reshaped
> to a n/k × k matrix **K** with the indices in **k** ﬁlling **K** along row
> direction. Another all false logic matrix **L** is created with
> the same size as **K**. An index in **K** in column a deﬁnes the
> element in the corresponding row of **L** in column a to be set
> to be true. As a result, each column in **L** deﬁnes a split of
> training and validation sets.

I'm pretty sure that the description got the naming of the vectors and matrices wrong, which added to my confusion. I'm guessing m/M and k/K are the same thing.

Y is described as the "binary coded class membership" matrix, so I assumed this example was for 3 classes, each having 3 samples. But when looking further at the description, it says that this is an example for 3 splits/partitions. So do the 3 columns of Y not actually represent the classes in the dataset, but the belonging of the samples to one of 3 partitions? But it is also clearly stated that the method preserves class distributions in its training and validation set, so I don't see how that's the case?

In my attempt to understand it, I also tried to sketch how this would look if Y had 4 columns instead of 3 (again with 3 samples in each column), but I didn't really understand how to form matrix M.

Basically my questions are: What do the columns in Y represent? Which dimensions do M and L have? How would this look for an example where M is not a square matrix?

I tried looking for additional explanations, but all sources seem to be pointing to either one of these papers.
Any help is appreciated.